# Change Width in Menu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'd like to know how set dinamic menu width in XAML. I read about '*' but in menu it done't work. I did it in C# like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menu1.Width = this.Width;
        toolBarPanel1.Width = this.Width;
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        menu1.Width = this.Width;
        toolBarPanel1.Width = this.Width;
    }
```

but i think better way set dinamic size in XAML can u say how i can do it?

Comment: Does it have the HorizontalAlignment property?  You might be able to do: HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" to make it stretch to the size of it's container?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to build a user interface in WPF. You'd better read about using a layout for your UI maybe `DockPanel` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your Menu inside a Grid, you can instruct the Grid to stretch the size of your menu no matter the window changes its size.

Answer (score 0):

"*" will take up available space. You can use ratios. For example:

```
1.5*
2*
1*
```

1.5 will be 1.5 times the width at the 1. 2 will be 2 times the width of the 1. This way you can have control over widths without making them fixed values.